# Detecting JMX connections via local server - how to do it?

Tags: java, connection, jmx

I submitted a version of this question back in Dec '13, but never got any comments so wanted to try again in case somebody else might see it.

JConsole allows a user to connect to a Java process via either a local connection (using the JVM's process ID) or via a remote URL (whether or not the process is on the local machine is irrelevant). I'd like to have a connection listener for the JMX ConnectorServer that will be notified when a connection is opened or closed. I can find the ConnectorServer object for a remote connection URL, and see the relevant connectionOpened() and connectionClosed() calls. Does anybody know how to do that for local (PID-based) connections? I've been unable to get hold of the ConnectionServer for local connections, in order to add a listener to it.

Any suggestions?
Dave

Comment: The traditional way to draw attention to an old question, is to put a bounty on it.

Comment: Thanks, Thorbjorn - I didn't know that.